# Contract violation expected when using a module from R6RS

Tags: racket, r6rs

I have the following module in `abc/main.rkt`:

```
#lang racket

(provide (all-defined-out))

(define (abc) 10)
```

Here's a short R6RS program which imports that module:

```
#!r6rs

(import (rnrs) (abc))

(display (abc))
(newline)
```

This error message appears at the bottom of the DrRacket window when that program is loaded:

> +: contract violation expected: number? given: #f argument position: 1st other arguments...: 0

I'm able to run the program successfully however.

Any suggestions on how to get rid of the error?

Comment: This works fine for me. Can you provide more details on your setup? What version of Racket?

Comment: Hello @AsumuTakikawa, I'm using 5.3.4 64-bit on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Are there any other files involved?

Comment: I ran the program on Windows 7 64-bit and I did not get the error.

Comment: Unable to reproduce error with any racket 5.*